# How can I get all the file names in a directory as a comma separated string in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, directory

I want to get all the names in a directory as a comma separated string so that I can pass them as a parameter to a cmdlet.

How can I get all the file names in a directory as a comma separated string in Powershell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

one way is:

```
 (dir  | % { $_.basename }) -join ','
```

Comment: in ps V3 you can do `((dir).basename) -join ','`  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Quickest/shortest way:

```
(ls).name -join ','
```

For specific folder-path:

```
(ls path\to\folder).name -join ','
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
(ls C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER | select -expandproperty name) -join ','
```

If there are subfolders in there that you want to avoid:

```
(ls C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | select -expandproperty name) -join ','
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be more comfortable with the classic Windows `dir`, here's a variant of [Eddie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618165/90802) (which used the *nix-like `ls`, which of course ps also supports):

`(dir -name) -join ','`

This would produce the exact same result as his `ls` example. (To be clear, this would work ONLY in powershell--as requested in the question here--but not in the Windows Command line.)

And if you wanted to remove folder names from the results (in either his or my example), add the -file switch: `(dir -file -name) -join ','` or `(ls -file).name -join ','`.

And of course you could follow the `dir` (or `ls`) with a pattern of files to be found, or a folder in which to look. These examples are simply getting ALL files in the current folder. To find all filename of exe's starting j, this would work:

`(dir j*.exe -file -name) -join ','`

Or to name a path as well, note that if the folder has spaces you must quote the path, as in:

`(dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\j*.exe" -file -name) -join ','`

FWIW, this `dir` in powershell is an alias of `Get-ChildItem`, and using `help dir` will show its many other args/switches.